# Async MethodInfo Invoke - cast return type dynamically

Tags: c#, asynchronous, expression, system.reflection

I am attempting to call an awaitable method via MethodInfo invoke.
The MethodInfo.Invoke() returns type object that needs to be cast as a Task before I can await it.  If I manually cast the return type with a generic parameter of Task, the process works correctly.

However, I have a number of these methods to call that have different return types.  How do I handle the return type?

```
public class Repository
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetListAsync(int criteria)
    {
        return new List<Foo> {new Foo {Bar = "1"}, new Foo {Bar = "2"}};
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Precache
{
    public static void RegisterPreCache(Repository instanceObject)
    {

        var preCachedType = typeof (Repository);

        var preCachableMethods =
            preCachedType
                .GetMethods();

        foreach (var cachableMethod in preCachableMethods)
        {
            var resultTask =
                (Task<IEnumerable<Foo>>) cachableMethod.Invoke(instanceObject,
                    new object[]
                    {1});
            Task.Run(async () => await resultTask).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the return type easily from cacheableMethod.ReturnType property.  How can I do the cast dynamically?  Without the cast, I cannot await the invocation.

I have tried casting simply as Task which of course does not work (EDIT: It does work).  I have tried passing all of the parameters into a new generic method, but if I do not specify the generic type must be a Task (where T : Task), I get a compile time error that there is no definition for GetAwaiter.

```
private static void CallExpression<T>(T returnType, MethodInfo     
    cachableMethod, object instanceObject, object[] parameters) 
{
    var resultTask = (T) cachableMethod.Invoke(instanceObject, parameters);
    Task.Run(async () => await resultTask).Wait();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: "I have tried casting simply as Task which of course does not work." - why "of course" here? I'd expect it to work, if the methods actually return a `Task` of some description. It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] here...

Comment: Jon you're absolutely right. I was operating under assumptions from previous iterations of the code. Simply casting as Task worked and allowed me to await the invocation. You did absolutely solve the problem for me, and I thank you for your help

Comment: @jeffj23: Also, you should really re-think the `Task.Run`/`Wait` thing. I don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Stephen!  I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With many thanks to Jon Skeet, was able to determine that the issue was the fact that I was making the cast too specific.

```
var resultTask = (Task) cachableMethod.Invoke(...)
```

allows the MethodInfo invocation to be awaited.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already posted:

```
var resultTask = (Task)cachableMethod.Invoke(...)
```

However, be aware:

1. You can [await on anything](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/) besides `Task` and `Task<T>`, so if your downstream method returns something that can be awaited on with an extension method, that approach will not work.
2. The problem number 1 can be a problem in future C# 7 feature, where [you can return a custom awaitable type](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-generalized-async-return-types) in async method besides `Task` or `Task<T>`